# python long running process crashing without error output

Tags: python, linux

I'm running a python script that does the following logical steps:

- Gets a list of hosts from a DB query
- For each of those hosts, gets a csv
- Processes the csv with Pandas
- Inserts the output in elasticsearch

It works well but as the list of hosts is large in some cases, it can take up to 6 days to finish some of the runs.

The problem is that sometimes it crashes without much information.
This is what the error looks like in /var/log/messages: abrt[3769]:

> Saved core dump of pid 24382 (/usr/bin/python) to
>   /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-02-05-10:33:42-24382 (631136256 bytes)
>   abrtd: Directory 'ccpp-2016-02-05-10:33:42-24382' creation detected
>   abrtd: Interpreter crashed, but no packaged script detected: 'python
>   /home/cloud/collection-all-es-commissioned.py' abrtd: 'post-create' on
>   '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-02-05-10:33:42-24382' exited with 1 abrtd:
>   Deleting problem directory
>   '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-02-05-10:33:42-24382'

It happens with python 2.6 and 2.7 in Oracle Linux.

Any ideas on how to find out the root cause and fix it?

Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: Have you tried adding print-statements in your code to see where it crashes?

Comment: Yep, it has a few try and prints there. But it doesn't print anything. Well, I'm running it via nohup and redirecting the stdout and stderr to a file. Which is a bit behind the actual running, do you think that may cause it? Other errors get printed straight away

Comment: It's tough to say. I googled around a bit, and there are a few sources that says its because the interpreter is broken. Are you running a python with anaconda?

Comment: Yeah, same here. I googled and in theory there should be a folder that you can use with a command to see what happened. But as the log shows it creates the folder, then deletes it. I'm using pandas, but not anaconda, I installed pandas through pip.

Comment: Right. If I were you I'd install Anaconda and use its version of Python instead. If the issue is that your interpreter is broken somehow, I think this would fix your issue. Also Anaconda has a better package manager (conda instead of pip).

Comment: Cool, I've got all the scripts running, and I've changed one setting that will make them use less memory. But if they crash again, will try with anaconda. Thanks!